# When dragged and on mouseup/mouseleave in the document I want to call my Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For slider range - when dragged and on mouseup/mouseleave in the document I want to call my Ajax request.

Explained:
When I mousedown to slide my slider I want to say isDown = "true" But it doesn't works.

Can anyone please help me with this and let me know how do I achieve this.

```
// Default 
isDown = false

$("#slider-range").find('a').mousedown(function(){
    isDown=true;
    console.log(isDown); // It works here!
});

console.log(isDown); // It doesn't works here

if(isDown)
{
    $(document).onmouseup(function() {
        return setAjaxRequest();
        isDown = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you defined `isDown` outside the mousedown callback? You won't be able to "see" it if you didn't.

Comment: Hi, yes I have defined isDown = false; on top of this function

Comment: My bad - of course it won't work, you are evaluating `isDown` after setting up `mouseDown()`. Try checking for `isDown` **inside** `onmouseup` callback.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with mouseup it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare isDown outside the event functions to share it between these functions !
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var isDown = false;

    // On a mousedown on a slide link
    $("#slider-range").find('a').mousedown(function(){
        isDown = true;
    });

    // on MouseUp on the document
    $(document).one('mouseup', function() {
        if (isDown) {
            return setAjaxRequest();
            isDown = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Sybio, this works but when I click any were on the document it keeps requesting for the ajax file on each click. So I tried your code with one() - Using $(document).one('mouseup', function(){ ... }) this now works!!

Comment: Hi I tried the above code it works but there was one problem on each clicked on document it was calling my ajax file. so i just added $(document).one('onmouseup',function() {...}); Now it works!! Thanks Sybio

Comment: Here is the final code:  $("#slider-range").find('a').mousedown(function(e){
   isDown=true;
   console.log(isDown);
    if(isDown)
    {
     $(document).one('mouseup',function(e) {
       setAjaxRequest();
       isDown = false;
     });
    }
    else
    {
     isDown = false;
    }
  });

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code:

```
    $("#slider-range").find('a').mousedown(function(e){
        isDown=true;
        console.log(isDown);
            if(isDown)
            {
                $(document).one('mouseup',function(e) {
                        setAjaxRequest();
                        isDown = false;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                isDown = false;
            }
    });
```